# Progress complete dialog window Android

Tags: android

So in my code I have it set so when someone pushes button1 it will start a download, and a progress bar appears and shows them the download. My problem is, the file is so small, it goes from 0-100% so fast you can even notice it, so I wanted to make a dialog popup when the download was complete. Heres my code:

```
public class v090 extends Activity {

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private Button startBtn;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.v090);
    startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startDownload();
        } }); 
}

private void startDownload() {
    String url = "https://docs.google.com/uc?   
authuser=0&id=0B6ocq4LWhNJkRlpXelpheGtnZUE&export=download";
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading...");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}



@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    int count;

try {

URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();

int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new    
fileOutputStream
("/sdcard/Android/data/com.snowbound.pockettool.free/Patches/shadermod.mod"    );



byte data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;

    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
return null;

}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
     Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
     mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
    dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}
}
}
```

Comment: just create the alertdialog in onPostExecute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly advice against a popup-dialog, it's bad practice because it breaks interaction with your app and forces the user to confirm. Do this only when absolutely necessary.

If you wan't more confirmation than the progress-bar to finish, use a `Toast` instead. It's safe to do this in the `onPostExecute`-method of your `AsyncTask` since anything in there happens on the UI thread after the background-task has finished:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
  dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
  Toast.makeText(v090.this, "Download finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

PS: By convention, the first letter of class-names in Java is usually capitalized.

Comment: Thanks, works great! But I have two questions. Just out of curiosity, how come class-names are usually capitalized? And could I make a download failed toast too? Maybe use try{ and {catch. I'm not sure what exception I would use though.

Comment: (Naming) Conventions make code cleaner and readable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java And yes, you can e.g. return an error message from your exception in the `doInBackground`-method, it's what you will get as a parameter in your `onPostExecute`-method. See the AsyncTask-documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html